# Не изменяется стандартная иконка Android-приложения

Tags: android, intellij-idea, icon

Здравствуйте.

Пишу приложение под `Android` в `Intellij Idea`, сунул `icon.png` в соответствующих разрешениях в папки: `drawable`, `drawable-hdpi`, `drawable-ldpi`, `drawable-mdpi`, `drawable-xhdpi`, `drawable-xxhdpi`. При компиляции и в эмуляторе и на девайсе отображается дефолтная иконка приложения.

Что я делаю не так?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Проверьте AndroidManifest.xml скорее всего там не icon, а:

```
<application
    ...
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    ...
```

Comment: Странно, но там вообще не было этой записи. Спасибо!